# receiving data using net.Server

Tags: node.js

I have problem in receiving the data, when I tried to telnet my server every time I type in the telnet, the server will log each character I typed, so how do I get all the data? or the complete data stream?

```
var svr = require('net');

svr.creteSerever(function(socket){

   console.log("client connected");

     socket.on('data',function(data){
        console.log("the socket",data.toString());
    });


});


svr.listen(3030, 'localhost', false, function () { 
    console.log('server listening in port 3030');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can collect the data until you have enough, or until the remote side is done:

```
var chunks = [];
socket.on('data', function(data) {
  chunks.push(data);
  // here you can check if you have enough
}).on('end', function() {
  var all = Buffer.concat(chunks);
  // here you have all the data that the client sent
});
```

**EDIT**: judging by your comments you're not so much interested in reading *all* the data, but in reading line-by-line. In that case, you can use the `readline` module:

```
var net      = require('net');
var readline = require('readline');

net.createServer(function(socket) {
  var rl = readline.createInterface({ input : socket });

  rl.on('line', function(l) {
    console.log('line:', l);
  });

}).listen(...);
```

Comment: why is it if i pressed enter,the server will not log the words that i typed in the telnet ?

Comment: about your comment  "// here you can check if you have enough". how would I peform that ?do I need to check the buffer size ?

Comment: yes I think this is what I want. so there is readline to use. Thank you it works.

Comment: I just want to ask one question, if my 30 clients(device) will simultaneously send buffer.. does the server can get all those buffer send by the clients?

Comment: @jemz it will create a buffer for each client/connection individually.

Comment: can I ask ,in your first part answer..chunks.push(data);
  // here you can check if you have enough...how can i check or how do i know that the data is enough ?I am confuse..lately I discover that your first answer is want to read the whole data what was being sent by clients

Comment: @jemz it really depends on your use case, but say that you're interested in only reading until the first occurrence of a particular token. In that case, you can check in the `data` handler to see if that token has been sent (in the array of chunks that you collected so far) without having to wait for _all_ the data to have been read (triggering the `end` handler).

Comment: ,sometimes my client send this kind of data http://pastie.org/10153215 it always end up 3 charachter ex: *55

Comment: so how do i check if the last data is having *45 ?

Comment: @jemz assuming that `all` is a Buffer: `all.slice(-3).toString() === '*45'`

Comment: but its not always 45

Comment: @jemz you should probably create a new question, comments aren't really meant for these types of things.

Comment: @roberklep what does this mean buffer.js:215
    buf.copy(buffer, pos);
        ^
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.Buffer.concat (buffer.js:215:9)

Comment: @jemz that you're probably trying to concatenate strings, not buffers.

Comment: @roberklep chunks.push(data.toString); this what I did in the .on('data')

Comment: @jemz if you're pushing strings, not buffers, use `chunks.join('')` instead of `Buffer.concat(chunks)`.

Comment: no error now but I have problem in realtime. I will wait  until the device is disconnected.I cannot do with the data that is being send if the device is not yet disconnected

Comment: @jemz sorry, I'm not gonna have a whole discussion in the comments. If you have specific stuff you want to ask you should open a new question.